# Trouble using an environment variable's value in VBS

Tags: xml, vbscript, environment-variables

I'm new to VBScript and wrote a little script that can modify an XML file; but I am having trouble putting the computer name in the XML.

I got the computer name from the `HOST` environment variable using these lines:

```
 Set wshShell = CreateObject( "WScript.Shell" )
 WScript.Echo wshShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings( "HOST=%HOST%" )
```

However, now I am unclear how to put it in a few paths inside the XML – meaning I want the computer name to be everywhere you see `%HOST%` below:

```
sWebcastFlash = "%HOST%:port/webcast/"
sWebcastInfra = "%HOST%/webcast/"
sWebcastTelephone = "%HOST%:port/telephone/"
```

`%HOST%` in the above strings did not expand into the `HOST` environment variable's value as I hoped.  What am I missing?

This is my full script:

```
Set wshShell = CreateObject( "WScript.Shell" )
WScript.Echo wshShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings( "HOST=%HOST%" )
'wshShell = Nothing


sWebcastFlash = "%HOST%:port/webcast/"
sWebcastInfra = "%HOST%/webcast/"
sWebcastTelephone = "%HOST%:port/telephone/"

'Create XMLDoc object
Set xmlDoc = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
xmlDoc.load "D:\Configuration\developer\developer-definitions.xml"

Set nWebcastFlash = xmlDoc.selectSingleNode("//clusters/cluster/servers/server/webcast-fms-url-for-flash")
Set nWebcastInfra = xmlDoc.selectSingleNode("//clusters/cluster/servers/server/webcast-fms-url-for-infra")
Set nWebcastTelephone = xmlDoc.selectSingleNode("//clusters/cluster/servers/server/webcast-fms-telephone-preview-url")
Set nWebcamUrl = xmlDoc.selectsinglenode ("//clusters/cluster/servers/server/webcam-self-test-url")
Set nHostName = xmlDoc.selectsinglenode ("//clusters/cluster/servers/server/host-name")
Set nHostAddress = xmlDoc.selectsinglenode ("//clusters/cluster/servers/server/host-address")
Set nAudUrl = xmlDoc.selectsinglenode ("//media-definitions/media-servers/on-demand-media-url/url-list/url/aud-url")
Set nFlashUrl = xmlDoc.selectsinglenode ("//flash-server-chat-list-url/flash-server-url")
Set nWebcamTest = xmlDoc.selectsinglenode ("//flash-server-webcam-self-url/webcam-self-test")

'Set the text node with the new value
nWebcastFlash.text = sWebcastFlash
nWebcastInfra.text = sWebcastInfra
nWebcastTelephone.text = sWebcastTelephone
'Save the xml document with the new settings.
strResult = xmldoc.save("D:\out.xml")
```

Comment: If you're new to working with VBScript, skip it altogether and instead use PowerShell. It's the way of the present and future for scripting on Windows and this task will be much easier there.

Comment: @Tomalak the post originally was tagged with VB.Net and Plutonix edited the tag out.

Comment: @alroc Ah, that's not been obvious (I'm using the mobile website, which is kind of limited.) Comment deleted.

Comment: @Tomalak if you're on a supported platform, give the Stack Exchange app a spin

Comment: @alroc I did, I found it not worth my time. It's not a lot more than a glorified proprietary single-purpose web browser. None of the intrinsic problems of the mobile website have been solved, with the exception of notifications, which I don't deem important enough to put up with the app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to assign the expanded `HOST` environment variable to a local variable and prepend it to the strings in which you want to use it:

```
Set wshShell = CreateObject( "WScript.Shell" )
host = wshShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings( "%HOST%" )
wshShell = Nothing


sWebcastFlash = host & ":port/webcast/"
sWebcastInfra = host & "/webcast/"
sWebcastTelephone = host & ":port/telephone/"
```

**Edit:**

@Tomalak raised a good point in his comment.  For the sake of completeness, you could also accomplish this with a call to `ExpandEnvironmentStrings` for each string in which you want to use the `HOST` environment variable's value:

```
Set wshShell = CreateObject( "WScript.Shell" )

sWebcastFlash = wshShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings( "%HOST%:port/webcast/" )
sWebcastInfra = wshShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings( "%HOST%/webcast/" )
sWebcastTelephone = wshShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings( "%HOST%:port/telephone/" )

wshShell = Nothing
```

As @Tomalak further pointed out, this involves a bit more code: it is needlessly repetitive in my view, but TMTOWTDI.

Comment: @Shachar Note that you *can* use `ExpandEnvironmentStrings` the way it was named - to expand environment variables in a larger string: `sWebcastFlash = WshShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%HOST%:port/webcast/")`. That works, but using a variable for the host name results in less code overall.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, in VBScript the value of an environment variable can be got inside the ExpandEnvironmentStrings method like this way:

```
' Get environment variable value:
Set wshShell = CreateObject( "WScript.Shell" )
host = wshShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings( "%HOST%" )
wshShell = Nothing
```

And, as @Tomalak said, other strings can be added inside the method:

```
Set wshShell = CreateObject( "WScript.Shell" )

sWebcastFlash = wshShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings( "%HOST%:port/webcast/" )
sWebcastInfra = wshShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings( "%HOST%/webcast/" )
sWebcastTelephone = wshShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings( "%HOST%:port/telephone/" )

wshShell = Nothing
```

But be careful when adding a string to right end of the ExpandEnvironmentStrings result after it finished, because it can give a null-terminated string, and it can cause a problem when adding other string to the end of null-terminated.

I had a stumbling-stone in CScript under Wine with ExpandEnvironmentStrings: it gives a null-terminated string, and due to some internal bug (or a feature?) it then cannot be concatenated normally with others from left, as it has the terminator zero character in right end. For example, this code may NOT work properly:

```
'Expanding and obtaining the variable value:
Set wshShell = CreateObject( "WScript.Shell" )
host = wshShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings( "%HOST%" )
wshShell = Nothing

' Adding strings to it's end.
' This may not work when a bug with null-terminated string concatenation present (this concatenation is likely ignored then):
sWebcastFlash = host & ":port/webcast/"
sWebcastInfra = host & "/webcast/"
sWebcastTelephone = host & ":port/telephone/"
```

If You have the problem with concatenating strings got from ExpandEnvironmentStrings then this workaround may be applied to remove the null-terminator character after getting environment variable, like this:

```
' Get environment variable value:
Set wshShell = CreateObject( "WScript.Shell" )
host = wshShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings( "%HOST%" )
wshShell = Nothing

' Removing the null terminator character from right end:
cTestChar=Asc(Right(host,1))
Do Until ((Len(host)=0) OR (cTestChar<>0))
  host=Left(host,Len(host)-1)
  cTestChar=Asc(Right(host,1))
Loop    

' Using the value to build other paths:    
sWebcastFlash = host & ":port/webcast/"
sWebcastInfra = host & "/webcast/"
sWebcastTelephone = host & ":port/telephone/"
```

Hope it will save some time to somebody...

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35702357)

Comment: Thanks, I have extended it to provide full answer.

Comment: This review result was largely due to you explicitly stating that you were trying to bypass the comment restrictions in posting this answer. Now that you have what looks like a proper answer, I've adjusted your answer to remove that statement.